# Rasppberry pi Remote Desktop Conection Problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, x11, xrdp

I have an problem with the remote desktop conection. I can conect to the device but on the screen I get this.

I got this problem after an reboot, and when i tried to reconect i got this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv59o.png)

I tried everithing, i did an uppdate and nothing happend, I tried to change the rezolution of the conection but the same resulatat.

Obs. For the multisesion I have use the export on d-buss.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use VNC? It's usually fairly straightforward. Otherwise, if you're using xrdp there's a discussion of possibly the same problem at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277905

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su] or [unix.se].